# UIImage memory issue

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, caching, uiimage

I am trying to create an application with a photos from a certain location on Instagram. I have successfully got all the details and image urls and am trying to put the photos into a tableview. Here is my code.

```
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        var instagramCell1:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("instagramCell1") as UITableViewCell
        if var imageURLString = allDataArray[indexPath.section]["image_standard"] as NSString! {
            ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(imageURLString, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
            //IMAGE
            var cellImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
            cellImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenWidth)
            instagramCell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            instagramCell1.addSubview(cellImageView)
        })
        }

        return instagramCell1
    }
```

To get the image I am using [swift image loader](https://github.com/natelyman/SwiftImageLoader). The problem is that when each image gets put into the table, it seems to continue adding to the memory (cache?) and even when you scroll back up it continues to add more. (I'd post an image but don't have enough rep) Anyway, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are doing an URL fetch everyTime the cell is dequeued, This will cause a lot of networking work.

As for the memory i'm not sure how do `swift image loader` work, but if i'm not mistaken the URL fetch causes the memory issues.

You can try to fetch all the images into some data structure before the UITableView is presented and inside of  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` just user this data structure to load the images into the cells

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help! Moved the swift image loader (asynchronous image loader) to the same place that the data was processed. Worked great!

Comment: Glad to help my friend!